# can't see the checkout option on amazon

Tags: amazon

can't see the checkout option on amazon

I have clicked the basket on the top right, this is the screen I then get.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well this is strange you can click on (cart icon) Basket option in top right corner to get into checkout option.

Comment: I did click on that that is the screen you are looking at. If you could provide a checkout URL then that might help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to "proceed to checkout", because the item in my basket is termed an "add on item", this is sometimes the case with a very cheap item.  They won't ship it out unless there is £20+ in the basket.